# I have two similar lines in python, one works but the second has Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to make a code to give me the angular coeficient, to analitic geometry, but i'm aways getting this stupid Syntax Error...

I already tried change the variable name, restart the code run, reopen VSCode, remove the comments, none of those worked.

```
x = (int(input("Whitch is x number?\n"))

y = (int(input("Whitch is y number?\n"))

test = (x1 + y1)
print(test)

input()
```

I was expecting those to just work, and concatenate x and y, but what i receive is a SyntaxError: invalid syntax no the line of:

```
y = (int(input("Whitch is y number?\n"))
```

i dont understand why it not works if it is almost identical to:

```
x = (int(input("Whitch is x number?\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many parentheses on the left-hand side. Try this:

```
x = int(input("Whitch is x number?\n"))
y = int(input("Whitch is y number?\n"))
```